# when using htmlspecialchars to escape double-quotes, why is ENT_QUOTES required when using ENT_SUBSTITUTE?

Tags: php, flags, htmlspecialchars

I noticed the following behavior when working with `htmlspecialchars` in php version 7.0.3:

```
php > echo htmlspecialchars('"');
&quot;
php > echo htmlspecialchars('"', ENT_SUBSTITUTE);
"
php > echo htmlspecialchars('"', ENT_QUOTES | ENT_SUBSTITUTE);
&quot;
```

We would like to escape double-quotes while also using the `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` flag. Notice that the double-quote does not get escaped when using only the `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` flag.

Is the `ENT_QUOTES` flag required with `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` if we want to escape double quotes? Why is this?

The [documentation for htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) does not say that `ENT_QUOTES` is required when using `ENT_SUBSTITUTE`. In fact, it seems to suggest the opposite – double-quotes should always get escaped unless the `ENT_NOQUOTES` flag is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401` is the *default* value for the `$flags` parameter. When you pass `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` ***instead***, you're overriding the default. It is now not applying `ENT_COMPAT` anymore, which is responsible for the quotes. If you want to *add* `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` to the default parameters, you should correctly write:

```
htmlspecialchars('"', ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE)
```

Comment: Makes sense. But then, in the documentation, what does "In case of an ambiguous flags value, the following rules apply" mean? When would those rules ever be applied?

Comment: Ambiguous would be things like `ENT_QUOTES | ENT_NOQUOTES` etc. What should it do there?

Comment: I think those rules are rather well spelled out. Certain flags' meanings conflict with each other, and it's spelled out what it does in those situations.

Comment: That's where I'm confused. Are those rules for conflicts only? "When neither of ENT_COMPAT, ENT_QUOTES, ENT_NOQUOTES is present, the default is ENT_COMPAT." My interpretation is that ENT_COMPAT should be the default in the first two examples I provided, which means that double-quotes should be getting escaped; however, this is not the case.

Comment: I agree. You may have uncovered a bug in PHP or an inconsistency in the documentation. Make sure your case is bullet proof and consider https://bugs.php.net.

Answer (score 2):

When you explicitly pass flags to `htmlspecialchars`, you **replace the default flags**.

`htmlspecialchars($data)` is equivalent to `htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401)`

`htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_SUBSTITUTE)` discards the rules from `ENT_COMPAT` and `ENT_HTML401` to **just** use the rules from `ENT_SUBSTITUTE`.

(And `ENT_COMPAT` causes double quotes to be converted).

Comment: Makes sense. But then, in the documentation, what does "In case of an ambiguous flags value, the following rules apply" mean? When would those rules ever be applied?